# JAVA Spring Rest API environment upgrade plan

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I am currently tasked to upgrade my application environment from it roots. It was never been touched since long time but now it has become a high priority application. The technologies we are using in this application are as follows.
Java 6,
Tomcat 6,
Spring 3.x,
Hibernate 3.x,
MySQL 5.1,
mysqlJDBC connector 5.1.7,
ehcache 1.1.2,
c3po 0.9.1.0 
I am fairly new to work on upgrade projects so trying to get any valuable suggestions from people over here.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, upgrade projects will cost much effort depend on backward compatibility (Most of them (and I am not sure with my term)). My advice, you have to do some research about all the technologies that involved in your project and what is the best version for your needs. In the last, prepare the scenario to upgrade it (maybe bug tackling and something else).

Last time I want to upgrade my system, I develop it from the scratch again because I didn't do enough research. LOL